# JMeter - jtl files in Blazemeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I have a set of JMeter -.jtl files . Is it possible to upload them in Blazemeter to get an executive summary report . The test was run in JMeter .

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the files to [BlazeMeter Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) service which can generate a [normal load test report](https://sense.blazemeter.com/examples/) out of JMeter .jtl files, Apache Benchmark result files, etc.

You can also [generate a HTML Reporting Dashboard out of the .jtl results file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) as simple as:

```
jmeter -g /path/to/file.jtl -o /path/to/folder/with/report
```